# How to import range as array, from Excel into Word document

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-word, range

I'm working on a VBA Word Macro to create a document with personalized headers.
I have a spreadsheet with the text to be inserted in the Headers (every row shall be inserted on an individual page).

To do so, I want to import the data from spreadsheet as an `Array` into Word, in order to get those texts in place.

I wrote a piece of code to open the spreadsheet and get a pre-defined range using `Select` method; I get an error on trying to pass this `Selection` to a `Range` object.

The error message is `Runtime Error 13: Incompatible types`.

I added an `If` loop to assure that the `Selection` is not empty, and it wasn't, for every time I ran the code.

```
Sub main()

    'Main procedure
    Dim app_Excel As Excel.Application
    Set app_Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        
    Dim wbk_srce As Workbook
    Set wbk_srce = app_Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\0_portolon\Dias.xlsm", , False)
    
    Dim wsh_srce As Worksheet
    Set wsh_srce = wbk_srce.Worksheets(3)
    wsh_srce.Activate
    
    cell_1 = CStr("A1")
    cell_2 = CStr("D216")
    
    Dim header_range As Range
    wsh_srce.Range(cell_1, cell_2).Select
    
    If Selection = Empty Then
        Debug.Print ("error")
    Else
        Debug.Print ("good")
    End If
    
    Set header_range = Selection    '<---Error
    
    Dim header_array() As Variant
    
    'header_array = header_range.Value
    
    'Call add_readers


End Sub
```

**Note: I added only the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library to VBA Word.**

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance,

Tiago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Word and Excel have a `Selection` object so when you refer to a selection in Excel you need to qualify it by prefixing it with your Excel Application variable, i.e. `app_Excel.Selection`.

You also need to do this with other objects that both applications have in common such as `Range`. Word will understand `Dim header_range As Range` as being a `Word.Range`, so assigning a selection in Excel to it isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you @Timothy Rylatt, I appreciate it. I named the Excel Application as `app_Excel` but VBA Word didn't recognize it as a reference; then I used `Excel.Range` and `Excel.Selection`, and the code worked fine.